# How to append only few items into one array in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

Well, basically all im trying to do is I get a list of weather from the API which is an array of each node of the array represents a weather data every 3 hours, now all I want is to append only the first **6** items into my own array to load up the tableView with them.

so my question is : how can I append only six items into my own array? :)

Comment: `let dataSource = Array(weatherData.prefix(6))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you have not posted any code, here is one example of how to do it.

```
var i = 0
for x in apiData{

    if i >= 6 {
        return
    } else {
        myArray.append(x)
        i += 1
    }
}
```

Note: this code will only append the first 6 items no matter what they are. If you want specific 6 items in the data the code will need to be modified, you will also need to provide more information in your question

Here is another way of doing so

```
if myArray.count == 6 {
    return 
}
```

Comment: Yes! it works, that what I was looking for :D, was close, I must practise working with for in loops, im used to loops in Java :) thanks bro btw didn't post code due to the fact that its a small problem so ye..

Comment: @AviSabag glad this helped you, please accept the answer if this is what you were looking for. Also, when asking a question, no matter how small, it is always best practice to post any code you may have already tried, no harm in doing so ":)

Comment: Got ya! will do it next time :) thanks once again mate, much love! and take care.

Comment: This looks more like C code. In Swift you would can something like `myArray.append(apiData.prefix(6))`

Comment: @MartinR you probably meant `append(contentsOf:)`

Comment: @JulianSilvestri collection and/or array has no `length` property

Comment: @JulianSilvestri `append(apiData.prefix(6))` would only work if `myArray` were declared as `[ArraySlice<Int>]`

Comment: @LeoDabus thank you much for catching my mistake, i meant to say count